# calculating geodesics!

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

I have a Riemannian metric $h$ on $\mathbb{R}$, where $h$ is as

$$ \begin{align*}   
   h=
   \left(\begin{matrix}
   \frac{1}{\frac12+y^2} &           0 &            0\\
   0 & \frac{1}{\frac12+x^2} & 0\\
   0 & 0 & \frac{1}{k-(x^2+y^2)}
   \end{matrix}\right)\end{align*},$$
with constant $k$. I found the geodesics as straight lines! But what is an interpretation for a non-Euclidean Riemannian metric with straight lines as geodesics.

Comment: A Riemannian metric on *what*? This is supposed to be on $\Bbb R^3$, but the metric is independent of $z$? And you found that *every* straight line is a geodesic?

Comment: Yes on $R^3$ and independent of $z$. The Christoffel symbols are not zero?

Comment: No, the Christoffel symbols are very much not zero. But this is an absolutely horrendous mess.

Comment: For example $\Gamma_{11}^1h_{11}=\langle\Gamma_{11}^1\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rangle=\langle\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}}^\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rangle =\frac12\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x},\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\rangle=0$
!!????

Comment: What about $\Gamma^2_{11}$ and $\Gamma^3_{13}$?

Comment: Yes you are right! Such a silly mistake that I did!